# Disable console logs in isomorphic-fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, fetch

I am using isomorphic-fetch https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch
and every time a response is returned whether successful or failed, I see a console log which falls under the debug category. Whence does it come? Can it be library specific? I couldn't find it in library source though. Or is it about Fetch API?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately we are not very good at mind reading, so we will need to see your code and error messages (everything that is relevant, really), in order to understand what is happening.

Comment: Cannot tell you anything without some code to look at!

Comment: I am not seeing these messages under the default configuration. [Example](https://runkit.com/57bd6dfab71a5c1400c2f95b/57eb9de1fd9ecd1400adad6c/branches/master). Can you provide a minimal example of the code which demonstrates this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to isomorphic-fetch library. It is a feature directly offered by browsers (at least in Chrome and Firefox).

## Chrome

For [[image]google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) you can disable it using the `Log XMLHttpRequests` checkbox inside the Developer tools "Console Setting":

> https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#additional_settings
>
> Open the DevTools settings, go to the General tab, and scroll down to the Console section for further Console settings.
>   [image: Chrome general settings]

## Firefox

For [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) you have the `Net` > `XHR` setting in the toolbar of the Console tab:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Console_messages#Filtering_and_searching
>   [image: tag:Firefox Console Filtering and searching]
>   To see only messages of particular categories, click the button labeled with that category ("Net", "CSS", and so on). Clicking the main part of the button toggles that category on or off, while clicking the arrow on the right gives you more fine-grained filter options within that category:
>
> ```
> Net
> - Errors
> - Warnings
> - XHR
> - Log
> ...
> ```